# Disappearing cookies from Request when remove Cookies from Response while Testing C#

Tags: c#, cookies, moq

I try to mock the system in order to test controller.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public static HttpContextBase TestController()
        {
            Container _container = GetContainer();
            // Setup Moq config for controller context
            var moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var moqResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var moqSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var moqServer = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("User");
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

            moqRequest.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://10.00.00:11111/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            moqRequest.SetupGet(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
            //moq Context
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(moqResponse.Object);
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Session).Returns(moqSession.Object);
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Server).Returns(moqServer.Object);
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(principal);
            moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.User.Identity.Name).Returns("UserName");
            var contextRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://10.0.0.00:11111/User/Login", "");
            var contextResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
            HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(contextRequest, contextResponse);
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            // Authenticate User
            IUsuarioAppService _usuarioApp = _container.GetInstance<IUsuarioAppService>();
            var usuario = _usuarioApp.AutenticarUsuario(username, password);
            var usuarioController = _container.GetInstance<UsuariosController>();
            usuarioController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new RouteData(), usuarioController);
            usuarioController.Login(true, "", usuario);

            foreach (var key in moqContext.Object.Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {
                var cookieItem = moqContext.Object.Response.Cookies[key];
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, cookieItem.Value);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                moqContext.Object.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            var controller = _container.GetInstance<HomeController>();
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
        }

        var scenario1 = controller.New(model1) as ViewResult;
```

The problem is that inside method `New` in `HomeController` I remove the cookies of Response, and then the all cookies of Request disappear. Normally it is not happening, only when I am testing.

```
        internal static void SetCookie(string key, object value)
        {
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value != null ? value.ToString() : null);
            cookie.Path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;

            if (value == null)
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);

            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(key);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
```

What can be the reseaon of this? Do I Add correctly cookies to HttpContext?

Comment: If within a controller why couple your code to `HttpContext.Current` while the controller has access to `HttpContext` via a local property?

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think the cookies are present on the request in the first place? As I read it

```
 moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
 moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
```

will mean that no cookies are ever set on the request

Comment: I am setting them below `moqContext.Object.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);`

Comment: True, but the whole point of the `Setup` method is that the object is mocked. You can call `Add` but that does not mean that it will actually preserve the value to the next call. A Mock is not the same as an instance

Comment: So when I do SetupGet(x => x.Request.Cookies) I should already pass the HttpCookieCollection fullfiled with cookies that Im gonna use?

Comment: Yes - I'm pretty sure that's what you need to do

Comment: What if information in cookies change every time I run test? Like ASPXAUTH  and SessionId?

Comment: Maybe try setting it directly on the request mock not as a nested property. `moqRequest.SetupGet(x => x.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());`